# Does anyone know where to get the disaggregated data from the 2013 Consumer Expenditure Survey by the Bureau of Labor Statistics?

Tags: data-request, spending

I am doing research in econometrics and am in need of the disaggregated data from the 2013 [Consumer Expenditure Survey](https://www.bls.gov/cex/). I would like to analyze it using R.

When looking for the data on the Bureau of Labor Statistics website I was unable to find it. I contacted them and got a response that essentially amounted to "it's on there" yet I still can't find it. Does anyone know if there is another source of this data?

Answer (score 1):

here's the microdata https://www.bls.gov/cex/pumd_data.htm

here's how to analyze with R
http://asdfree.com/consumer-expenditure-survey-ces.html